# get custom post archieve by month

Tags: custom-post-type-archives

I want to make a custom post archieve template where I will display only the custom post by month..

I added this in archieve-news_letter.php

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'news_letter', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

/* Include the post format-specific template for the content. If you want to
                 * this in a child theme then include a file called called content-___.php
                 * (where ___ is the post format) and that will be used instead.
                 */
                get_template_part( 'newletter', get_post_format() );
```

where `news_letter` is my custom post...by this I am getting all post without any sorting of month, means I  am getting all month post in December link.

to make archieve link I used this:

```
<li><?php wp_get_archives(array('type' => 'monthly','order'=>'ASC')); ?></li>
```

any help would be appreciate..

Thanks for your time and sharing knowledge... :)

Answer (score 0):

I had some problem with `wp_get_archives`, you can try my solution of this issue

```
function get_cpt_archives( $cpt, $echo = false ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = %s AND post_status = 'publish' GROUP BY YEAR(wp_posts.post_date), MONTH(wp_posts.post_date) ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC", $cpt);
$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

if ( $results ){
    $archive = array();
    foreach ($results as $r){
        $year = date('Y', strtotime( $r->post_date ) );
        $month = date('F', strtotime( $r->post_date ) );
        $month_num = date('m', strtotime( $r->post_date ) );
        $link = get_bloginfo('siteurl') . '/' . $cpt . '/' . $year . '/' . $month_num;
        $this_archive = array( 'month' => $month, 'year' => $year, 'link' => $link );
        array_push( $archive, $this_archive );
    }

    if( !$echo )
        return $archive;
    foreach( $archive as $a ){
        echo '<li><a href="' . $a['link'] . '">' . $a['month'] . ' ' . $a['year'] . '</a></li>';
    }
}
return false;
}
```

put this in functions.php of your theme.

Then call this function where you need:

```
    <?php get_cpt_archives('post_type', true); ?>
```

`'post_type'` - change this to your post type name.

Second parameter:

`true` - it's a list with `<li>`

`false` - it's an array.